# How to remove 1 character from a column in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a column in my Excel file which contains different values. All these values begin with a letter and continues with a number.

I would like to know how to remove that letter and obtain only the number. Keep in mind that each value can have a different length.

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that SO is not free code writing community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

`=MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1),"")
```

or

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

There are countless ways to do that...

Answer (score 0):

use simple function in excel itself

=left(cellname,no. of charcters)
=left(A1,8) will give only first left characters and same can be used right/mid